# WebAPI returning either XML or NULL, to Firefox (want JSON)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, firefox, asp.net-web-api

I have an ASP.NET WebAPI webservice that returns an object:

```
/// <summary>
/// upload a single file, as a new attachment, or overwrite an existing attachment
/// </summary>
/// <returns>new attachment, if created</returns>
[HttpPost, ActionName("uploadAttachment")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> uploadAttachment(string jobid)
{
    if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);

    await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

    var attachment = [...];

    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, attachment);
}
```

... where "attachment" is a POCO object containing the information I need to return.

I'm calling it using XMLHttpRequest:

```
AttachmentService.prototype.uploadAttachment = function(jobid, name, imageData, notes, callback)
{
    var url = [...];

    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('name', name);
    formData.append('notes', notes);
    formData.append('imageData', imageData);

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.addEventListener('load', function(e)
    {
        var response = {};

        if (e.target.status == 200)
        {
            response.success = true;
            response.data = JSON.parse(e.target.response);
        }
        else
        {
            response.success = false;
            response.message = e.target.message;
            response.data = null;
        }
        callback(response);
    });

    xhr.open('POST', url, true);

    //xhr.responseType = 'json';

    xhr.setRequestHeader("authenticationToken", CORE.getAuthToken());
    xhr.send(formData);
};
```

This works fine, in IE11 and Chrome. In Firefox 33, e.target.response is XML, not JSON.

I've done some browsing around the web, and have seen a number of suggestions, both client and server side. What seemed simplest was to specify the xhr.responseType, as in the comment in the code above.

And that doesn't work.

When I set "xhr.responseType = 'json'", e.target.response comes back null.

Ideas?

### Additional info

Tried looking at the request headers in Fiddler.

In Chrome:

```
 Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
```

In IE11:

```
 Accept: */*
```

In Firefox:

```
 Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
```

So that does seem to be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the header to `application/json`

```
x.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/json; charset=utf-8');
```

Comment: If I do that, when I load the page from Chrome I get an HTTP 415, and when I load the page from Firefox I get an internal server error. Color me confused.